# Mail: Separate unread counts (badges) on dock icon for different accounts

Tags: software-recommendation, mail.app, dock

I have multiple accounts configured in Mail and I would like to see the separate unread counts in the dock icon.

I was looking at [dockstar](http://ecamm.com/mac/dockstar). When I google I see that another plugin Mailbadger is also available (the [homepage](http://www.tonyallevato.com/) is down for quite sometime now, and the download available via [macupdate](http://www.macupdate.com/info.php/id/25088/mail-badger) and [others](http://www.google.com/search?q=mailbadger) seem to be outdated)

Is there another/better app/plugin for customizing Mail's dock icons?

Comment: dockstar is exactly what you want, why searching for more?

Comment: @balexandre Just to know whether there are other alternatives, which *might* be better.

Comment: I believe Dockstar is possibly the best option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all the software I searched and see the detailed specs, [Dockstar](http://ecamm.com/mac/dockstar/) is **the best choice** for the feature you are requesting.

Comment: I have my personal mail and my office mail configured in Mail.app. I would want to see the separate unread counts. _Thought_ this might be helpful. Now that you say _I still don't get why..._ it has got into my head whether it would really be helpful... will try and let you know :-)

Comment: I have the same (2 personal accounts, 1 company account, plus 2 more for my own companies), but I still dont get it ... every time it has a number, I check it. period. :)

Comment: Sadly, Dockstar is not compatible with 10.9, and eCamm are no longer developing it. However, they are hoping to pass development to another developer: http://www.ecamm.com/mac/dockstar/faq.html